# How to find the pids of ancestors

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, kernel, pid

I am not able to get the pids of the ancestors

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  pid_t ppid = getppid();

  while (ppid != 0) {
    printf("Process ID: %d, Parent process ID: %d\n", pid, ppid);
    pid = ppid;
    ppid = get_parent_of(ppid);  // What can be used here?
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If used `getppid()` instead of `get_parent_of(ppid)`, the above code runs infinitely as the value of ppid doesn't change as it gives the parent pid of the current process.

How can we find the pids of the entire ancestors of a given process?

Comment: In Linux, you could use the 4th field of `/proc/$pid/stat`

Comment: `pid = ppid;` - you don't expect it to change the current process ID, do you?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Think of each loop pass finding a the process of ppid. They OP is asking what to use in place of `getppid()` to obtain the pid of the the parent of `ppid`.

Comment: `getpid` and `getppid` are system calls that work from the _current_ pid, which _can't_ be changed. Under linux [as mentioned by ikegami] we can parse `/proc/<pid>/status` (which is readable text) and look for the `Ppid:` line. Then, loop until we get to the top.

Comment: If Linux: [Listing all the parent processes of the main process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74605520/2505965)

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

`getpid` and `getppid` are system calls that work from the current pid, which *can't* be changed.

[AFAIK], there is *no* syscall that does the equivalent of `getppid` and allows a pid argument.

Under linux [as mentioned by ikegami] we can use `/proc`. We can parse `/proc/<pid>/status` (which is readable text) and look for the PPid: line and extract the ppid value. Then, loop until we get to the top.

---

Here is some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    char file[100];
    char buf[1000];

    while (1) {
        printf(" %d",pid);
        sprintf(file,"/proc/%d/status",pid);

        FILE *xf = fopen(file,"r");
        if (xf == NULL)
            break;

        pid_t ppid = 0;

        while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),xf) != NULL) {
            char *key = strtok(buf,": \n");
            if (key == NULL)
                continue;

            if (strcmp(key,"PPid") == 0) {
                char *val = strtok(NULL," \n");
                ppid = atoi(val);
                break;
            }
        }

        fclose(xf);

        if (ppid == 0)
            break;

        pid = ppid;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is some sample output from my system:

```
 2592302 6839 4716 3128 1
```